# Website for provider-hosted app

Tags: provider-hosted-app

Environment:
SharePoint Web Applications:
[image]
Configured appcatalog and app url. No issues adding SharePoint-hosted apps or apps from the store. They all go to http://prefix-587436.CustomName-apps.ml

I am trying to add a provider-hosted app. Whether I set app's site to be on its own, created in IIS http://ProviderHostedApp, or in  http://CustomName-apps.ml site, I receive an error:
http://providerhostedapp/SampleAppForTesting/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2FCustomName%3A17003&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag..
DNS address could not be found

DNS settings for providerhostedapp are like this:
[image]

Any hints or suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that machine I added another record pointing directly to the IP and it solved the issue.

On another I enabled ports for listening to that address and it also worked without any DNS records.